# Plugin suggestion: Find broken links

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I recently changed a few categories, so I know I have a bunch of broken links now. 
Instead of spending hours going through previous posts and fix them manually, I want to use a plugin that can do that for me.

My friend Google told me about the "[Broken Link Checker](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/broken-link-checker/)" plugin which seems to be quite popular, but for whatever reason it doesn't work for me not matter what I try.
I tried to find another similar plugin, but thus far without success.

Do you know of any other plugins that basically do the same as the "Broken Link Checker", but might work for my installation?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It's not really a plugin, but have you considered using [Google Webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/)?  Also, possibly helpful [bonus article](http://sixrevisions.com/website-management/find-remove-broken-links/).

Comment: Thank you. The article has some nice and useful methods that I'll try right now! :)

Comment: Try [Slim SEO Link Manager](https://wpslimseo.com/products/slim-seo-link-manager/) which provides reports of all links on your site with corresponding statuses (not just 4xx/5xx - broken, but also 3xx - redirected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [WP Link Validator - Detect Broken Links](http://codecanyon.net/item/wp-link-validator-detect-broken-links/2049931?WT.ac=search_item&WT.seg_1=search_item&ref=straightforward&WT.z_author=smart_techie) plugin. Looks like it should help you. Pay attention that this plugin is not free.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm looking for a plugin free of charge :)